# Unwrapping causes object stacking issues, affecting coloring/materials

Tags: uv

When I unwrap in Blender (image with the orange plane), I encounter an issue where my objects are stacking on top of each other. Upon importing into Clip Studio (image with the pink G-pen), I am unable to add color/material to the objects because, since they overlap, it paints multiple pieces instead of just the one I want. It seems that the unwrapped pieces are stacking on top of each other. Is there a fix for this?

[image][image]